# What is the syntax for a ruby inequality in where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the proper syntax to query where owner is not current_user:

```
.where(owner_id: != current_user.id, recipient_id: current_user.id, owner_type: "User")
```

I tried this:

```
where(['current_user.id <> ?', :owner_id ], recipient_id: current_user.id, owner_type: "User")
```

And Got:

```
undefined method `%' for ["current_user.id <> ?", :owner_id]:Array
```

Comment: Have you tried `where('owner_id != ?', current_user.id)`?

Answer (score 1):

I posted a solution in the comment, but you can also do something like

`.where("owner_id != #{current_user.id} AND recipient_id = #{current_user.id} AND owner_type = \"User\"")`

Comment: I think a double where seems to work like: .where('owner_id != ?', current_user.id).where(recipient_id: current_user.id, owner_type: "User").limit(10) any difference in speed or anything?

Comment: your answer gave me PGError: ERROR:  column "User" does not exist

Comment: try lowercase User... `user`

Comment: This might work too: `.where("owner_id != #{current_user.id} AND recipient_id = #{current_user.id} AND owner_type = 'User'")`

Answer (score 1):

try using a separate `where` method call for each condition, these will generate sql `AND`

```
Something.where("owner_id <> ?", current_user.id)
  .where("recipient_id = ?", current_user.id)
  .where("owner_type = ?", "User")
```